# How to run an action after response has been fully sent in Scotty / WAI

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-wai

Upon a GET request, my Scotty webapp will run some computation and store its result in a temporary file, which it sends as the response using [`file`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.12/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html).

Now I would like to run some cleanup (i.e. delete the temporary file) *after* the file has been sent. Scotty does not seem to include a way for doing so.

Is there is any functionality in WAI for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wai gives us a function [`responseStream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseStream)

```
responseStream :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> StreamingBody -> Response
```

that constructs a [`Response`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Response) out of a [`StreamingBody`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:StreamingBody), which is actually a function

```
type StreamingBody = (Builder -> IO ()) -> IO () -> IO ()
```

that, given a "write" action, and a "flush" action, finds some bytes somewhere and performs all the writing and flushing.

wai also provides us with a ready-made [`responseFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseFile) function:

```
responseFile :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> FilePath -> Maybe FilePart -> Response
```

but it doesn't delete the file at the end. Could we modify it in some way? It seems that we can, with the help of the [responseToStream](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseToStream) auxiliary function

```
responseToStream :: Response -> (Status, ResponseHeaders, (StreamingBody -> IO a) -> IO a)
```

that "opens up" an already constructed `Response`, allowing us to tweak things.

Like this:

```
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status (status200)
import System.Directory (removeFile)

responseFileDeleting' :: FilePath -> Response
responseFileDeleting' filepath = 
    let (status,header,streamer) = 
            responseToStream $ responseFile status200 [] filepath Nothing
     in responseStream status header (\write flush ->
             -- this would be a good place to put a bracket, if needed
             do streamer (\body -> body write flush)
                removeFile filepath)
```

(Note: the type of `streamer` is a bit mind-twisting because of all the higher-orderness.)

This solution has the disadvantage that requests have to wait until the file is deleted in order to complete. Another option could be to send filepaths to some kind of [concurrent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:concurrently_) [queue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-chans) that performed the deletions in another thread.